# how to stop one function using another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
dragscroll();
window.jQuery("div").hover(function (){
//stop dragscroll();
});

window.jQuery("div").mouseleave(function (){
dragscroll();
});
```

Comment: https://cdn.rawgit.com/asvd/dragscroll/master/dragscroll.js

Comment: Ah okay. So let's see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dragscroll.reset()`:

```
dragscroll();
jQuery("div").mouseover(function (){
  //stop dragscroll();
  dragscroll.reset();
});

jQuery("div").mouseleave(function (){
  dragscroll();
});
```

Comment: @ErekleChumburidze Updated answer. Kindly check?

Comment: thx I do all with your help )

Comment: @ErekleChumburidze Welcome, Merry Christmas.